# pandas TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: debugging

`my code below

`final = today_with_balance.copy()` final['Variance'] = (final['Closing price'] - final['Previous price'])/final['Previous price']
`final['Variance'] = final['Variance'].abs()`your text final.loc[final['Variance']<=-.07, 'Comment'] = 'Variance less than -7%'
`final.loc[final['Variance']>=.07, 'Comment'] = 'Variance more than 7%'` final[final['Comment'].notnull()]
`final.to_csv('Data/Equities/final_output.csv', index = None)

`please help debugging the error.

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'```